Binary foreign array to lisp array
I am reading a binary file of data that represents 1, 2 and 3 dimensional arrays of 32 and 64 bit floats, along with a few integers.  The file is designed to be read by a C program, where they can declare the arrays and then point the variables to various places in an mmap sequence. Their reader is less than 20 lines of code because they're just walking the pointer.
It seems to me that such a thing should be possible with CL. There's a few libraries that solve the opposite problem, passing lisp vectors to C in a way that avoids GC like static-vectors, cffi:with-pointer-to-vector-data, FFA, etc.
In this case, I allocate the memory via the implementation's mmap function, so GC isn't a problem.  I've considered using ccl::array-data-and-offset and sb-c::array-storage-vector and point them to the correct offset in the mmap'ed file.
Has anyone got any good ideas on how to map a memory region to a lisp array without copying or displacement?  Performance is important, as there's a lot of matrix multiplications going on. I'd love a portable solution, but covering SBCL and CCL is good enough for now.
Edit: A 'helpful' administrator apparently didn't bother to read the question carefully, and marked it as too similar to 'How to mmap a file on Linux?'.  I suggest they re-read the question and note that:

I have already used mmap for the data
it asks how to read the mmapped memory into Common Lisp arrays without copying.


This question is similar to: How to memory map a file in Common Lisp on Linux?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think when you mmap the file, the file object acts like an array whose contents are in the file. When you read from the mapped file, it's analogous to using AREF. There's no copying involved.

There is cffi:mem-aref and the like, but no other array semantics and only one-dimension.  The mmap'ed file does act like a contiguous array of octets, and since both C and CL have row major arrays it should in theory be possible to point the array to the underlying storage.  Using ccl::array-data-and-offset seems like a hack though (and non-portable), and possibly octet->float conversion. I'm wondering if anyone has any better ideas, or if I missed a system/library out there for this kind of binary array manipulation.  I may just have to accept copying, but these are GB sized arrays.

I don't have any real experience with CL but... if you can memmap the file, that just means it's available to you as a flat piece of memory, like anything you'd get from C or some system APIs. so then you're in a position to apply anything and everything that adapts between "memory" and CL semantics. you can peek and poke it, you can treat it as a stream (you could have done that to the file itself already), you can define structures on top to abstract the access to the memory, ... surely there is some way in the ecosystem of CL to take an array/matrix as flat memory and use it?

maybe you just need to find the right library... https://numcl.github.io/numcl/ IDK if that can handle arbitrary binary memory but at least it provides N-dimensional arrays and operations.

Unless the implementation directly supports this, in my experience it's a mistake to massage the internals of arrays.  Even if you can persuade the system that the data of an array is where you want it to be there's then a whole exciting question of whether the GC knows about this.
Instead, it's almost certainly better to simply invent arrays yourself.  This sounds insane, but it's actually pretty easy, and can have pretty good performance.
For instance, if you have a blob of memory which you know is a row-major 2d-matrix (say) of doubles and you know the number of rows (which I assume you find out by grovelling into the data you have) then if you can persuade the implementation to fetch and store doubles into appropriate offsets into that blob, you can write code which treats it like a matrix in all the interesting respects.  And that code can be fast.
Below is some code I wrote which uses CFFI to talk about double-float matrices.  In CFFI the accessor you need is mem-aref.  The macro with-double-float-matrix-accessors defines local accessor functions for these things which is a hack slightly inspired by MACLISP.  Those accessors, at least in theory, should be quick.
You will need collecting to use this.
(defpackage :ts
  (:use :cl :cffi :org.tfeb.hax.collecting))

(in-package :ts)

(deftype matrix-index ()
  `(integer 0 (,array-dimension-limit)))

(deftype matrix-rm-index ()
  `(integer 0 (,array-total-size-limit)))

(defparameter *matrix-access-checked* t) ;compile time

(defmacro with-double-float-matrix-accessors ((&rest bindings) &body forms)
  ;; Bind local accessor functions for double matrices
  (multiple-value-bind (accessors initforms
                        vars row-vars row-forms col-forms size-vars)
      (with-collectors (accessor initform var row-var row-form col-form
                        size-var)
        (dolist (b bindings)
          (destructuring-bind (a i rf cf) b
            (accessor a)
            (initform i)
            (let ((s (symbol-name a)))
              (var (make-symbol s))
              (row-var (make-symbol (concatenate 'string s "-ROWS")))
              (row-form rf)
              (col-form cf)
              (size-var (make-symbol (concatenate 'string s "-SIZE")))))))
    `(let ,(mapcan (lambda (var initform row-var row-form)
                     `((,var ,initform)
                       (,row-var ,row-form)))
            vars initforms row-vars row-forms)
       (declare (type matrix-index ,@row-vars))
       (let ,(mapcar (lambda (sv rv cf)
                       `(,sv (* ,rv ,cf)))
              size-vars row-vars col-forms)
         (declare (ignorable ,@size-vars))
         (declare (type matrix-rm-index ,@size-vars))
         (flet ,(mapcan (lambda (accessor var row-var size-var)
                          `((,accessor (r c)
                              (declare (type matrix-index r c))         
                              ,@(if *matrix-access-checked*
                                    `((assert (< (* r c) ,size-var)
                                              (r c)
                                              "out of range")
                                      '()))
                              (mem-aref ,var ':double
                                        (+ (* r ,row-var) c)))
                            ((setf ,accessor) (n r c)
                             (declare (type double-float n)
                                      (type matrix-index r c))
                             ,@(if *matrix-access-checked*
                                   `((assert (< (* r c) ,size-var)
                                             (r c)
                                             "out of range")
                                     '()))
                             (setf (mem-aref ,var ':double
                                             (+ (* r ,row-var) c)) n))))
                 accessors vars row-vars size-vars)
           (declare (inline ,@(mapcan (lambda (accessor)
                                        `(,accessor
                                          (setf ,accessor)))
                                      accessors))
                    (ignorable ,@(mapcan (lambda (accessor)
                                           `((function ,accessor)
                                             (function (setf ,accessor))))
                                         accessors)))
           ,@forms)))))

Here's a function to multiply two such matrices into an array (probably not very well optimised):
(defun double-float-matrix-multiply->array (a b s
                                            &optional
                                              (c (make-array
                                                  (list s s)
                                                  :element-type 'double-float)))
  (declare (type matrix-index s)
           (type (array double-float (* *)) c))
  (with-double-float-matrix-accessors ((a a s s)
                                       (b b s s))
    (dotimes (row s c)
      (dotimes (col s)
        (loop with sum of-type double-float = 0.0d0
              for k below s
              do (incf sum (* (a row k)
                              (b k col)))
              finally (setf (aref c row col) sum))))))


I've been looking at this problem for more than a week now, and I came to a similar conclusion.  There are still a few libraries out there that might work, like clblas that need investigating.
I think that the GC may be easily worked around, either with mmap or static-vectors, so I haven't given up hope yet.
